# How do I get rid of the Read More feature in Outlook?

Tags: email, outlook

I am using Outlook 4.2222.2. A few updates ago, it started adding a Read More button about midway through long emails.

[image: Read More button]

I now have to hit Read More to continue, which takes me to a spot in the app where I have to hit the X to get back to the reading pane (and therefore can't move the email to another folder, etc. without exiting).

I searched through the app's settings and did not find one that allowed me to disable it, and a Google search left me with the impression that not many had encountered this feature at all.

How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if you use the browser, unfortunately there is no option that will remove that button. Your best bet would be to change your mailbox settings. Try to see if you can make your mailbox text size smaller, then go to see if there are options, you can try changing message height to large, also below there are settings saying how should rows be aligned, set it to switch between one and multiple rows based on screen size. You may have to play around with those settings. If none of those options work, go to your settings and make your global text size for all apps smaller. That's what I did for my phone.

Comment: This button applies to reading messages, rather than appearing in the mailboxes area.  Good suggestions about font sizes, but I'd like to avoid a ton of workarounds.